# Passing form values to the next html page

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom, local-storage

I created these three files home.html,test.js and info.html. I want to pass the data in the home.html to info.html. When the input was just one it worked but when I added the second input it stopped working.
Please find the code below

#Home.html#

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title>HOME PAGE</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Transfer your name</h1>
        <form action="info.html">
            <input type="text" name="first" id="myname">
            <input type="text" name="last" id="mlname">
            <input type="submit" name="button" id="sender" onclick="passvalue()">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**info.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>INFO PAGE</title>
    </head>
    <body>
     
        A:<span id="result"></span>
        B: <span id="last"></span>
   
        <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>`
```

**test.js**

```
function passvalue(){

    let fname=document.getElementById("myname").value;
    let lname=document.getElementById("mlname").value;

    localStorage.setItem("textvalue",fname);
    localStorage.setItem("namevalue",lname);

    return false;
}
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=localStorage.getItem("textvalue");
document.getElementById("last").innerHTML=localStorage.getItem("namevalue");
```

Comment: What do mean by stopped working ? i am guessing most likely you are overwriting the `innerHTML`  of `results`

Comment: Any errors thrown in browser dev tools console?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping the only value that shows is the fname element . the second element, lname, does not show on the info.html

Comment: @AileenAkpalu yes thats because you are overwriting existing HTML - add a `+` sign

Comment: @charlietfl No errors

Comment: You don't appear to be setting the lname text in the span #last the way you do with #result

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Could you please elaborate, I do not seem to see where the issue is

Comment: @charlietfl I realized I omitted it out here, but on my editor I have that command

Comment: @AileenAkpalu thats should work then. If it a separate span you are loading into ! Check the browsers application to see whether there is a value  (lname) or not in localStorage

Comment: @AlwaysHelping its still not showing the second result. I don't know how that is possible. Yeah there is no lname in the localStorage

Comment: @charlietfl I have seen an error. this is the error message Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at test.js:10

Comment: the document needs to have an element with the id you are trying to use in document.getElementById or else the function will return null

Comment: So it looks like you use same code on both pages but only one page has that element

Comment: @AileenAkpalu Add this **only** in your `info.html` as script => `<script>  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("textvalue");document.getElementById("last").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("namevalue");
</script>`

Comment: I ran exactly your code on my machine, in windows 10, Chrome and it works fine. I'm using VSCode Live Server.